# How do I data-bind = "visible : active" in div

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

hi this is my code snippet:

```
<div class="showtimes" data-bind="visible: showHide">
 <div data-bind="template: { name: 'movie-grouped-showtimes-template', data: $data }"></div>
</div>
```

I want to toggle `showHide` off and on using the following:

```
<a class="icon arrow" data-bind="click: $parent.showtimes">
```

can't I just set up a variable `showHide` in my view Model, like the following:

`self.showHide = ko.observable(false)` ... Hide

`showHide(true);` ... show

and can I set it using the `click : $parent.showtimes`, like in the following:

```
<a class="icon arrow" data-bind="click: $parent.showtimes"></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to set a function in the viewmodel that binds to the button's click (or modify an existing one, like showTimes in this case) to toggle the value of showHide.

Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/EfrainReyes/LNzDL/

```
var vm = {
    showHide: ko.observable(false),
    toggle: function() {
        this.showHide( !this.showHide() );
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

I didn't add any other elements to the example because the question seems to be targeted more towards showing/hiding the div.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know if this will work because the click event is part of another binding. but thank you

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel You should consider accepting this answer though. It answers the question you asked. If this answer doesn't work for your specific scenario you should (possibly in a new SO question) include those details in the question. Good luck!